# Magento overriding core file from module

Tags: magento

I've overridden a core Varien file by moving it to the /local/ namespace and editing it there.    I have a module the depends on that file being modified.   How do I package up the module, including the modified Varien file, if the Varien file is in /local/Varien, and my module is in /local/module_name?

Comment: Distributed modules should be in the `community` codepool unless you are packing it for personal / org internal use.

Comment: local or community is not a big deal. But you should not do it inside local/Varien, but use rewrite. Put this file in your module, extending the Varien one. And in the config.xml configure the rewrite.

Comment: @dagfr  I need to change a function in Varien.   By doing this rewrite, I'd be creating a new file that extends Varien.  Would I just redeclare the function in the new file?

Answer (score 0):

You should try and use XML based override with syntax like:

```
<blocks>    
    <enterprise_giftregistry>
        <rewrite>
            <customer_list>MyNamespace_MyModule_Block_MyBlock</customer_list>
        </rewrite>
    </enterprise_giftregistry>
</blocks>
```

There's more information available on this page for example, or by googling 'xml rewrite overriding':

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/how_to_overload_a_controller